# Java Reading of a dynamic log file using scanner word by word

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a log file word by word using a scanner and using the code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String word = scanner.next();
}
```

But the problem is that this stops after it reaches the end of the file but I need to read it as it gets generated

I tried this to solve this using the below code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 
while(true){
    while(!scanner.hasNext()){
         Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    String word = scanner.next();
}
```

But the code does not seem to work and gets stuck in the while loop even when the log file has more data appended to it.
Can someone point out what i am doing wrong.

Comment: why is that a problem? If the file ends, you can't read more words. What are you *actually* trying to do? Watch for log output and read it in as it gets generated? (if so, add that to your post. If not, add that to your post. etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an small snippet for reading a log file for another system. I used BufferedReader instead of Scanner. Because it will run until the end of file and still reading. Instead of using the Scanner Next. 
`readLine() Doc:`

```
 * @return     A String containing the contents of the line, not including
 *             any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the
 *             stream has been reached
```

And My Snippet

```
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
                while (true)
                {

                    strLine = br.readLine();
                    if(strLine!=null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(strLine);
                    }else{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                }
```